# Missing operand after '=' operator

Tags: c#, dataview, rowfilter

I have this line of code which uses a dataview `view_1` and I'm trying to filter the datagridview by product_name and its size using the `RowFilter`.
Here is the code:

```
view_1.RowFilter = "product_name = '" + cboProduct.Text + "' AND size = " + cboSize.Text + "";
```

And when I try to run the application it says `Missing operand after '=' operator`.
So what is that missing operand?

Comment: take a whitespace Between `'" + cboProduct.Text + "'` `AND`

Comment: A good example to use `String.Format`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what is wrong I tried to filter first if the text of `cboProduct` and `cboSize` is empty or if no selection has been made and now it's working. Thank you.
Here is the code

```
if (cboProduct.Text == string.Empty || cboProduct.SelectedIndex == -1 || cboSize.Text == string.Empty || cboSize.SelectedIndex == -1)
            {
                view_1.RowFilter = string.Empty;
            }
            else
            {
                view_1.RowFilter = "product_name = '" + cboProduct.Text + "' AND size = " + cboSize.Text + "";
            }
```

Answer (score 8):

<strike>You have a missing white-space at `'AND`</strike>

So replace

```
'AND
```

with

```
' AND
```

Is size a string-column or an int-column? If it's a string you need quotation marks around too:

```
AND size = '" + cboSize.Text + "'";
```

or even better, use `String.Format` as others have commented since it insreases readability:

```
view_1.RowFilter = string.Format("product_name = '{0}' AND size = '{1}'"
            , cboProduct.Text
            , cboSize.Text);
```

Comment: @Harvey: Is size a string-column or an int-column? If it's a string you need quotation marks around too. `AND size = '" + cboSize.Text + "'";`. Btw, instead of rewriting your question to remove the wrong part you should have added instead the information that it's still not working. Now my answer makes no sense anymore but it could have been  helpful for others with a similar problem.

Comment: Okay I get it..after putting a white-space I tried to put it in the else clause and now it's working. Thank you.

Comment: @Harvey: Also edited my answer to show you how you can use `String.Format` to increase readability.

Answer (score 4):

Write like this

```
view_1.RowFilter = "product_name = '" + cboProduct.Text + "' AND size = " + cboSize.Text + "";
```

Missing White space problem

**Edit**

You can also use `string.Format`

```
view_1.RowFilter =  String.Format("product_name = '{0}' AND size = {1}", cboProduct.Text,cboSize.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the variable `product_name` is having a value that contains a space then the value needs to be wrapped in square brackets in the filter expression:
So,just wrap the variable `product_name` by pair of square brackets like this 
`[product_name]`

```
view_1.RowFilter = "[product_name] = '" + cboProduct.Text + "' AND size = " + 
cboSize.Text + "";
```